# break points in the typescript source not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a node module and an example application along with it. I'm trying to add debugging breakpoints to one of the source files in the module but I can not get VSC to recognize it. Using the latest versions of Typescript and VSC.

*EDIT:* This is supposed to be a node application, no browser to worry about.

*EDIT2:* Here is repo with the issue [repo with problem.](https://github.com/amejias101/TS-problem)
Here is my current setup

```
├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── main.d.ts
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── main.js.map
├── examples
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── main.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
```

I'm developing the example in `examples/index.js` and I'm setting the breakpoints in `src/main.ts`

this is my VSC launch.json configuration

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch TypeScript",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/examples/index.js",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
      "args": [
        "--nolazy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2015",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "declaration": true,
      "rootDir": "src"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "examples",
      "dist"
    ]
}
```

my gulp task

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  var tsResult = tsProject.src('tsconfig.json')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

  return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('dist')),
        tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: false, sourceRoot: 'src'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    ]);
});
```

how the sourcemaps are coming put

```
{"version":3,"sources":["main.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";CAAC,...CAAC","file":"main.js","sourceRoot":"src"}
```

Comment: Typescript files never get executed, they get converted to Javascript and that is what is ran. I'm not sure if you can put code breaks in Javascript files in VS, but you can in developer tools.

Comment: I should also clarify that these are node applications

Comment: Oh, well then I have no clue, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is using "program" to reference the filename "index.js" in the corresponding "outDir". In your case it's looking for "dist/index.js".

Having an alternate entry file is causing the confusion. To avoid the name collision, "examples/index.js" needs to be a unique filename(exampleApp.js?) that doesn't exist in "dist".

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change "outDir" to "${workspaceRoot}/dist". The Node debugger uses that flag to find your generated scripts.